# Facebook returns 502 error for my url but not for a different url of mine?

Tags: debugging, response, facebook-social-plugins, gateway

Hello Facebook debugger tool is returning a 502 error on my url

> http://www.tfuhq.com/guides/player/how-to-pick-your-username-for-transformers-universe/

but returns a 200 code for:

> http://www.tfuhq.com/guides/

why is this?

Comment: Do you remember what was the problem here? I'm currently having similar problem and I don't have any idea why. :)